# Understanding async await instruction during a HttpClient request

Tags: c#, async-await

Let's say I have a solution composed of 2 projects. An old WinForm classic project. In this old project, I have a login window. On click "OK" of this login window, I start an event that will call a REST API. Both applications start at the same time in debug mode.

Somewhere in my code, I have this code:

```
public async Task<User> Login(string username, string password)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = await Client.GetAsync($"api/Login?login={username}&password={password}");
    if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
        return new User();
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    var userDto = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<UserDto>();
    var user = userDto.ToUser();
    return user;
}
```

On the first line when I call the `Client.GetAsync` I call my API. In my API I properly receive the call and I properly return an Ok with my User object or I return another code. It works. My API works. But then nothing. My client never continues. It seems `Client.GetSync` waits for something. I never go on the next step where I evaluate the StatusCode.

```
public async Task<User> Login(string username, string password)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = Client.GetAsync($"api/Login?login={username}&password={password}").Result;
    if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
        return new User();
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    var userDto = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<UserDto>();
    var user = userDto.ToUser();
    return user;
}
```

Same code without the await I have no problem. My code run till the next step. Proof my API is not the problem.

This is clear it is an issue related to await/async. I must do something wrong but what? Can you help me? Is it related to the debugger?

For more information here is a picture of my code before

[image]

And after I click for the next step. Note my call stack is empty and code is still running.

[image]

As requested here is the code where I call the login. I just added the Async word before the Sub and changed the _authService.Login(username, password).Result by await _authService.Login(username, password)

I works now.

```
Private Async Sub ButLogin_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles butLogin.Click
    DataProxies.SetToken()
    Dim _authService As IAuthenticationService = New AuthenticationService()


    Dim username As String = txtLogin.Text
    Dim password As SecureString = New NetworkCredential(String.Empty, txtPwd.Text).SecurePassword

    Dim auth As Tuple(Of Boolean, User) = Await _authService.Login(username, password)
    If (auth.Item1) Then
        Dim user As User = auth.Item2
        Name = $"{user.FirstName} {user.LastName}"
        ApiInformations.ApiToken = user.SessionToken
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `Same code without the await I have no problem` on the contrary, you have a big problem. You blocked the thread waiting for the asynchronous operation. This means you blocked the UI thread on a desktop application or blocked a thread that could serve another request in a web application. Blocks start with spinwaits which means you're pegging the CPU without doing anything. In a server application this not only reduced throughput, it *increases* CPU utilization and can lead to an app pool recycle under heavy load

Comment: If you have a problem, debug your code, add proper exception handling and find out what's wrong. Perhaps the other server never responded. Perhaps there was an exception that wasn't caught. Or perhaps the result couldn't be deserialized to `UserDto`

Comment: I click F10 to go next step then nothing happen. I can wait forever, nothing happen.

Comment: Use a debugging proxy like Fiddler to see the *actual* requests and responses.

Comment: `I click F10 to go next step then nothing happen.` that doesn't mean anything. It doesn't mean that the remote service responded at all. That's why you need to use Fiddler and see what's actually going on

Comment: Where *does* that service run? If it's part of the same solution, debugging means it's frozen as well

Comment: Another possibility is that you are making more than 2 concurrent calls to the same service. Back when HTTP was only used to serve HTML pages there was a guideline that one client should only make 2 concurrent calls per domain. You can remove that limit in the HttpClientHandler settings

Comment: The remote service responded for sure. I have log and when I remove the "await" I get the response. When you say something can be frozen, yes this is also my feeling but what? I updated the image with my code and threads.

Comment: The picture doesn't help except raise the prospect that *two* calls are made from the two different methods. *What does Fiddler show ?* Is there a response when you experience blocking or not?

Comment: `HttpClient.GetAsync` works. `await` works. If your code blocks, you have to see what's going on in the code. Perhaps there's no response yet. Perhaps you have a desktop application and *block* the UI thread at the top, preventing `await` from returning to it. You can easily do that with eg `var task=Login(...);MessageBox.ShowDialog(..);, await task;`.  Removing `await` or adding `.Result` doesn't prove anything. Without the actual code, withouth knowing what's going on, one can only guess

Comment: "Perhaps you have a desktop application and block the UI thread at the top, preventing await from returning to it." I think it is that because my small login window re-appears somehow and is blocked.

Comment: You shoulds show _how_ this Login method is called, all the way to the top of your code. async/await is a chain, all steps must be correct. I think you have a WinForms problem, not a HttpCLient problem.

Comment: By adding Async in my ButtonLogin event handler and await before the call to the login I could resolve this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I just added the Async word before the Sub and changed the _authService.Login(username, password).Result by await _authService.Login(username, password)

The general guidance is ["Don't block on async code"](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). This is one of the [asynchronous programming best practices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).

Blocking on asynchronous code is bad because [`await` works by capturing a "context"](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) by default, and resumes executing the `async` method in that context. One context is the UI context, which causes the `async` method to resume executing on the UI thread.

So the deadlock you were seeing was caused by blocking the UI thread. The code was calling the `async` method and then blocking the UI thread until that `async` method completed. However, the `await` in that `async` method captured the UI context, so it was waiting for the UI thread to be free before it could complete. The UI thread was waiting for the `async` method and the `async` method was waiting for the UI thread: deadlock.

The *reason* your fix worked is that the UI thread is no longer blocked waiting for the `async` method, so there's no more deadlock.